# Leaflet draw not working with Django - shape never finishes

Tags: django, leaflet, leaflet-draw, django-leaflet

My Django app just started having a weird problem where when I try to draw a shape on a map with Leaflet and Leaflet draw, the shape never finishes. That is, when I click and drag to draw a shape, the shape draws, then when I release the mouse, the shape looks finished but a new shape immediately starts drawing (with the mouse released). If I press "esc" the shape looks finished. But, the web console has the error:
`MouseEvent.mozPressure is deprecated. Use PointerEvent.pressure instead. leaflet.js:5:268`

I tried updating `django-leaflet` from pip. I'm not sure where else `leaflet.js` would be coming from (it's not a static file). I'm using a MacBook, tried with track pad and USB mouse.

Anyone know how this started happening and how I can fix it? Bizarre that it was working and now is not without me changing anything.

Here's some relevant code:

```
    {% load leaflet_tags %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    {% leaflet_js %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css"/>
    <script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
        console.log('created'); //Never prints to console
        var type = e.layerType;
        var layer = e.layer;
        map.addLayer(layer);
        geoJSON_obj = layer.toGeoJSON();
        if (type === 'circle') {
            var rad = layer.getRadius();
            geoJSON_obj.properties.radius = rad;
        }
        var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(geoJSON_obj);
        document.getElementById('id_image__location').value = jsonObj;
        });
    }
```

Using Django 2.2.3 and Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an error on my part: the line `document.getElementById('id_image__location').value = jsonObj;` didn't work because the element didn't exist (should have been `id_location`). This, apparently, was making the larger function not work and the draw objects to not create properly.

After correcting that, everything works as it should (even with the `MouseEvent.mozPressure is deprecated` warning). Just posting here in case someone else has a similar issue.